# How to find a keyword inside XLS file via c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a folder with 100 **.xls** files.
And I need to find a **keyword** inside these files.
My program must open each file and find a **keyword**.
If it is found then this file will be shown in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this: http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/ And just traverse each file attempting to find the keyword in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

- [Loading and reading the Microsoft Excel file contents using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Excel_Application_in_C_.aspx)
- [Opening and Navigating Excel with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx)
- [Excel Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelReader.aspx)